# Log4Net doesn't log from one machine, but from others with same config

Tags: c#, log4net

I have a c# assembly exe with a log4net xml config.

the exe and config is sitting on a network drive.
execution and logging from 2 machines is ok.

from a third machine, no logging at all occurs.

any ideas?

Comment: Can you post your config file?

Comment: Maybe a permission/cas problem. Have you checked the CasPol from the third machine? (CasPol.exe)

Answer (score 1):

Does the machine definitely have access to the log file and pick it up at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

The log directory was read only rights.